# How to improve login speed in Pure-FTPd

Tags: pureftpd

I'm using Pure-FTPd on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS machine (focal).
Packages are the following:

```
pure-ftpd-common/focal,now 1.0.49-4 all [installed,automatic]
pure-ftpd/focal,now 1.0.49-4 amd64 [installed]
```

I configured virtual users in PureDB and I disabled PAM and Unix authentications.
These are the configuration keys:

```
AnonymousOnly: no
BrokenClientsCompatibility: yes
ChrootEveryone: yes
Daemonize: yes
DisplayDotFiles: yes
DontResolve: yes
FSCharset: UTF-8
IPV4Only: yes
MaxClientsNumber: 50
MaxClientsPerIP: 5
MaxIdleTime: 60
MinUID: 30
NoAnonymous: yes
PAMAuthentication: no
PassivePortRange: 35000 36000
ProhibitDotFilesWrite: no
PureDB: /etc/pure-ftpd/pureftpd.pdb
TLS: 0
UnixAuthentication: no
UserBandwidth: 1000
VerboseLog: yes
```

Login is extremely slow (5-7 seconds) connecting from localhost.
How can I improve its speed?

Comment: What does your log shows? Is some login step failing?

Comment: Nothing is failing, it's just slow on `pass` command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and then I found out that it's just argon2 hashing of the password. So if you create a virtual user, you have to give a password when creating, but after that generate password hash with another algorithm and change the encrypted password in the `pureftpd.passwd` before running `pure-pw mkdb`. Also don't use `pure-pw passwd` or you will get a user with slow login.

Use for example mkpasswd and md5:
`echo wantedpass | mkpasswd -s5`

With md5 hashed passwords the login is very fast.

Answer (score 0):

How do you change the encryption method from argon1 to md5 after generating the password with mkpasswd ?

I tried to change the string "argon2" to "md5" in pureftpd.passwd but it didn't work.